# Is get start Page Token for creating drive push notification channel and getting list of changes is same?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am using `googleapis` (drive v3) npm and `oauth2client` to get drive items. I use `drive.changes.getStartPageToken()` to create channel for webhooks(push notifications). I am successful in getting the notification. Now when I get the notification, initially was syncing all the drive items again. But now I wanted to change the flow as fetching only the changes in the drive using `drive.changes.list()`. In `drive.changes.list()` also should I get start page token again and hit it? what is the difference between the start page token that I use here and the start page token that I use when creating a channel? Is there any other way to fetch only changes of the files when webhooks hits us?

Comment: I think you can use that, as described in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-changes) they used the last saved start token for this user or the current token from `getStartPageToken()`. Try using  [`changes.watch`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch) method to subscribe for updates to the change log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `drive.changes.list()` you need to provide a pageToken generated by `drive.changes.getStartPageToken()`. When you generate a startPageToken, all the future changes in your Drive will appear on `drive.changes.list()` if you use that token.

After calling `list()`, you need to get newStartPageToken from the response. Then you will send this newStartPageToken to get new changes and so on.

If you want to receive push notifications instead of requesting new changes everytime, I suggest you to read [this article](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push).

Comment: I have already implemented push notification. When I receive a push notification, I call the changes.list API to get changes. But I don't get appropriate changes. Now I'm facing an issue where the changes array is always empty and I get only newPagetoken for the initial request  and not the next page token.

Comment: If you generate a newPagetoken and you use it on changes.list, you will only see changes after the token was generated. So you cannot generate a pageToken when you receive a push notification, maybe that's why you are receiving an empty array?